# How to fit texture image to canvas (responsive)

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

i'm trying to create a slider using PIXI.

I'm basically using the code in this tutorial:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2017/10/10/liquid-distortion-effects/

Everything works fine but i was trying to create a non-fullscreen slider (contained into a div) and I would like to make the images cover-fitted to the canvas.

Thanks for any help, if you need more information I will be glad to provide it.

**EDIT**

Here is the example I was working on. In index.html you'll find the call to the initialization, in main.js you'll find the core code

http://wakko.altervista.org/slider-webgl/

**EDIT 2**

here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cnv89kL1/10/

```
(function() {

window.CanvasSlideshow = function( options ) {



  //  SCOPE
  /// ---------------------------      
  var that  =   this;



  //  OPTIONS
  /// ---------------------------      
  options                     = options || {};
  options.stageWidth          = options.hasOwnProperty('stageWidth') ? options.stageWidth : 1920;
  options.stageHeight         = options.hasOwnProperty('stageHeight') ? options.stageHeight : 1080;
  options.pixiSprites         = options.hasOwnProperty('sprites') ? options.sprites : [];
  options.centerSprites       = options.hasOwnProperty('centerSprites') ? options.centerSprites : false;
  options.texts               = options.hasOwnProperty('texts') ? options.texts : [];
  options.autoPlay            = options.hasOwnProperty('autoPlay') ? options.autoPlay : true;
  options.autoPlaySpeed       = options.hasOwnProperty('autoPlaySpeed') ? options.autoPlaySpeed : [10, 3];
  options.fullScreen          = options.hasOwnProperty('fullScreen') ? options.fullScreen : true;
  options.displaceScale       = options.hasOwnProperty('displaceScale') ? options.displaceScale : [200, 70];
  options.displacementImage   = options.hasOwnProperty('displacementImage') ? options.displacementImage : '';
  options.navElement          = options.hasOwnProperty('navElement')  ?  options.navElement : document.querySelectorAll( '.scene-nav' ); 
  options.displaceAutoFit     = options.hasOwnProperty('displaceAutoFit')  ?  options.displaceAutoFit : false; 
  options.wacky               = options.hasOwnProperty('wacky') ? options.wacky : false;
  options.interactive         = options.hasOwnProperty('interactive') ? options.interactive : false;
  options.interactionEvent    = options.hasOwnProperty('interactionEvent') ? options.interactionEvent : '';
  options.displaceScaleTo     = ( options.autoPlay === false ) ? [ 0, 0 ] : [ 20, 20 ];
  options.textColor           = options.hasOwnProperty('textColor') ? options.textColor : '#fff';
  options.displacementCenter  = options.hasOwnProperty('displacementCenter') ? options.displacementCenter : false;
  options.dispatchPointerOver = options.hasOwnProperty('dispatchPointerOver') ? options.dispatchPointerOver : false;
  options.fitCoverSprites = options.hasOwnProperty('fitCoverSprites') ? options.fitCoverSprites : false;



  //  PIXI VARIABLES
  /// ---------------------------    
  var renderer            = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer( options.stageWidth, options.stageHeight, { transparent: true });
  var stage               = new PIXI.Container();
  var slidesContainer     = new PIXI.Container();
  var displacementSprite  = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage( options.displacementImage );
  var displacementFilter  = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter( displacementSprite );



  //  TEXTS
  /// ---------------------------    
  var style = new PIXI.TextStyle({
    fill: options.textColor,
    wordWrap: true,
    wordWrapWidth: 400,
    fontSize: 36
  });



  //  SLIDES ARRAY INDEX
  /// ---------------------------    
  this.currentIndex = 0;



  /// ---------------------------
  //  INITIALISE PIXI
  /// ---------------------------      
  this.initPixi = function() {

    renderer.backgroundColor = 0x000000;
    // Add canvas to the HTML
    document.querySelector('.canvas-here').appendChild( renderer.view );


    // Add child container to the main container 
    stage.addChild( slidesContainer );


    // Enable Interactions
    stage.interactive = true;

    console.log(renderer.view.style);

    // Fit renderer to the screen
    if ( options.fullScreen === true ) {
      renderer.view.style.objectFit = 'cover';
      renderer.view.style.width     = '100%';
      renderer.view.style.height    = '100%';
      renderer.view.style.top       = '50%';
      renderer.view.style.left      = '50%';
      renderer.view.style.webkitTransform = 'translate( -50%, -50% ) scale(1.2)';           
      renderer.view.style.transform = 'translate( -50%, -50% ) scale(1.2)';           
    } else {
      renderer.view.style.objectFit = 'cover';
      renderer.view.style.width     = '100%';
      renderer.view.style.height    = '100%';
      renderer.view.style.maxWidth  = '100%';
      // renderer.view.style.top       = '50%';
      // renderer.view.style.left      = '50%';
      // renderer.view.style.webkitTransform = 'translate( -50%, -50% )';           
      // renderer.view.style.transform = 'translate( -50%, -50% )';          
    }


    displacementSprite.texture.baseTexture.wrapMode = PIXI.WRAP_MODES.REPEAT;


    // Set the filter to stage and set some default values for the animation
    stage.filters = [displacementFilter];        

    if ( options.autoPlay === false ) {
      displacementFilter.scale.x = 0;
      displacementFilter.scale.y = 0;
    }

    if ( options.wacky === true ) {

      displacementSprite.anchor.set(0.5);
      displacementSprite.x = renderer.width / 2;
      displacementSprite.y = renderer.height / 2; 
    }

    displacementSprite.scale.x = 2;
    displacementSprite.scale.y = 2;

    // PIXI tries to fit the filter bounding box to the renderer so we optionally bypass
    displacementFilter.autoFit = options.displaceAutoFit;

    stage.addChild( displacementSprite );

  };



  /// ---------------------------
  //  LOAD SLIDES TO CANVAS
  /// ---------------------------          
  this.loadPixiSprites = function( sprites ) {


    var rSprites = options.sprites;
    var rTexts   = options.texts;

    for ( var i = 0; i < rSprites.length; i++ ) {

      var texture   = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage( sprites[i] );
      var image     = new PIXI.Sprite( texture );

      if ( rTexts ) {
        var richText = new PIXI.Text( rTexts[i], style);
        image.addChild(richText);

        richText.anchor.set(0.5);
        richText.x = image.width / 2;
        richText.y = image.height / 2;                     
      }

      if ( options.centerSprites === true ) {
        image.anchor.set(0.5);
        image.x = renderer.width / 2;
        image.y = renderer.height / 2;            
      }
      // image.transform.scale.x = 1.3;
      // image.transform.scale.y = 1.3;



      if ( i !== 0  ) {
        TweenMax.set( image, { alpha: 0 } );
      }

      slidesContainer.addChild( image );

    } 

  };



  /// ---------------------------
  //  DEFAULT RENDER/ANIMATION
  /// ---------------------------        
  if ( options.autoPlay === true ) {

    var ticker = new PIXI.ticker.Ticker();

    ticker.autoStart = options.autoPlay;

    ticker.add(function( delta ) {

      displacementSprite.x += options.autoPlaySpeed[0] * delta;
      displacementSprite.y += options.autoPlaySpeed[1];

      renderer.render( stage );

    });

  }  else {

      var render = new PIXI.ticker.Ticker();

      render.autoStart = true;

      render.add(function( delta ) {
        renderer.render( stage );
      });        

  }    


  /// ---------------------------
  //  TRANSITION BETWEEN SLIDES
  /// ---------------------------    
  var isPlaying   = false;  
  var slideImages = slidesContainer.children;    
  this.moveSlider = function( newIndex ) {

    isPlaying = true;


    var baseTimeline = new TimelineMax( { onComplete: function () {
      that.currentIndex = newIndex;
      isPlaying = false;
      if ( options.wacky === true ) {
        displacementSprite.scale.set( 1 );
      }          
     },onUpdate: function() {

        if ( options.wacky === true ) {
          displacementSprite.rotation += baseTimeline.progress() * 0.02;      
          displacementSprite.scale.set( baseTimeline.progress() * 3 );
        }

    } });

    baseTimeline.clear();

    if ( baseTimeline.isActive() ) {
      return;
    }        

    baseTimeline
      .to(displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: options.displaceScale[0], y: options.displaceScale[1]  })
      .to(slideImages[that.currentIndex], 0.5, { alpha: 0 })
      .to(slideImages[newIndex], 0.5, { alpha: 1 })          
      .to(displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: options.displaceScaleTo[0], y: options.displaceScaleTo[1] } );

  };



  /// ---------------------------
  //  CLICK HANDLERS
  /// ---------------------------         
  var nav = options.navElement;

  for ( var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++ ) {

    var navItem = nav[i];

    navItem.onclick = function( event ) {

      // Make sure the previous transition has ended
      if ( isPlaying ) {
        return false;
      }     

      if ( this.getAttribute('data-nav') === 'next' ) {

        if ( that.currentIndex >= 0 && that.currentIndex < slideImages.length - 1 ) {
          that.moveSlider( that.currentIndex + 1 );
        } else {
          that.moveSlider( 0 );
        }

      } else {

        if ( that.currentIndex > 0 && that.currentIndex < slideImages.length ) {
          that.moveSlider( that.currentIndex - 1 );
        } else {
          that.moveSlider( spriteImages.length - 1 );
        }            

      }

      return false;

    }

  }



  /// ---------------------------
  //  INIT FUNCTIONS
  /// ---------------------------    

  this.init = function() {


    that.initPixi();
    that.loadPixiSprites( options.pixiSprites );

    /*
    if ( options.fullScreen === true ) {
      window.addEventListener("resize", function( event ){ 
        scaleToWindow( renderer.view );
      });
      scaleToWindow( renderer.view );  
    }
    */


  };




  /// ---------------------------
  //  INTERACTIONS
  /// ---------------------------
  function rotateSpite() {
    displacementSprite.rotation += 0.001;
    rafID = requestAnimationFrame( rotateSpite );
  }

  if ( options.interactive === true ) {

    var rafID, mouseX, mouseY;

    // Enable interactions on our slider
    slidesContainer.interactive = true;
    slidesContainer.buttonMode  = true;       

    // HOVER
    if ( options.interactionEvent === 'hover' || options.interactionEvent === 'both'  )  {

      slidesContainer.pointerover = function( mouseData ){
        mouseX = mouseData.data.global.x;
        mouseY = mouseData.data.global.y;   
        TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: "+=" + Math.sin( mouseX ) * 100 + "", y: "+=" + Math.cos( mouseY ) * 100 + ""  });   
        rotateSpite();
      };      

      slidesContainer.pointerout = function( mouseData ){
        TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 0, y: 0 });
        cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
      };     

    }

    // CLICK
    if ( options.interactionEvent === 'click' || options.interactionEvent === 'both'  ) {

      slidesContainer.pointerup = function( mouseData ){
        if ( options.dispatchPointerOver === true ) {
          TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 0, y: 0, onComplete: function() {
            TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 20, y: 20  });        
          } });            
        } else {
          TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 0, y: 0 });                      
          cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
        }

      };     

      slidesContainer.pointerdown = function( mouseData ){
        mouseX = mouseData.data.global.x;
        mouseY = mouseData.data.global.y;         
        TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: "+=" + Math.sin( mouseX ) * 1200 + "", y: "+=" + Math.cos( mouseY ) * 200 + ""  });   
      };    

      slidesContainer.pointerout = function( mouseData ){
        if ( options.dispatchPointerOver === true ) {
          TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 0, y: 0, onComplete: function() {
            TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 20, y: 20  });        
          } });            
        } else {
          TweenMax.to( displacementFilter.scale, 1, { x: 0, y: 0 });                      
          cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
        }

      };              

    }

  }


  /// ---------------------------
  //  CENTER DISPLACEMENT
  /// ---------------------------
  if ( options.displacementCenter === true ) {
    displacementSprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    displacementSprite.x = renderer.view.width / 2;
    displacementSprite.y = renderer.view.height / 2;        
  }


  /// ---------------------------
  //  START 
  /// ---------------------------           
  this.init();


  /// ---------------------------
  //  HELPER FUNCTIONS
  /// ---------------------------
  function scaleToWindow( canvas, backgroundColor ) {
    var scaleX, scaleY, scale, center;

    //1. Scale the canvas to the correct size
    //Figure out the scale amount on each axis
    scaleX = window.innerWidth / canvas.offsetWidth;
    scaleY = window.innerHeight / canvas.offsetHeight;

    //Scale the canvas based on whichever value is less: `scaleX` or `scaleY`
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    canvas.style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
    canvas.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";

    //2. Center the canvas.
    //Decide whether to center the canvas vertically or horizontally.
    //Wide canvases should be centered vertically, and 
    //square or tall canvases should be centered horizontally
    if (canvas.offsetWidth > canvas.offsetHeight) {
      if (canvas.offsetWidth * scale < window.innerWidth) {
        center = "horizontally";
      } else {
        center = "vertically";
      }
    } else {
      if (canvas.offsetHeight * scale < window.innerHeight) {
        center = "vertically";
      } else {
        center = "horizontally";
      }
    }

    //Center horizontally (for square or tall canvases)
    var margin;
    if (center === "horizontally") {
      margin = (window.innerWidth - canvas.offsetWidth * scale) / 2;
      canvas.style.marginTop = 0 + "px";
      canvas.style.marginBottom = 0 + "px";
      canvas.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
      canvas.style.marginRight = margin + "px";
    }

    //Center vertically (for wide canvases) 
    if (center === "vertically") {
      margin = (window.innerHeight - canvas.offsetHeight * scale) / 2;
      canvas.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
      canvas.style.marginBottom = margin + "px";
      canvas.style.marginLeft = 0 + "px";
      canvas.style.marginRight = 0 + "px";
    }

    //3. Remove any padding from the canvas  and body and set the canvas
    //display style to "block"
    canvas.style.paddingLeft = 0 + "px";
    canvas.style.paddingRight = 0 + "px";
    canvas.style.paddingTop = 0 + "px";
    canvas.style.paddingBottom = 0 + "px";
    canvas.style.display = "block";

    //4. Set the color of the HTML body background
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

    //Fix some quirkiness in scaling for Safari
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf("safari") != -1) {
      if (ua.indexOf("chrome") > -1) {
        // Chrome
      } else {
        // Safari
        //canvas.style.maxHeight = "100%";
        //canvas.style.minHeight = "100%";
      }
    }

    //5. Return the `scale` value. This is important, because you'll nee this value 
    //for correct hit testing between the pointer and sprites
    return scale;
  }      


};




imagesLoaded(document.body, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));

        var spriteImages = document.querySelectorAll( '.slide-item__image' );
        var spriteImagesSrc = [];
        var texts = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < spriteImages.length; i++ ) {

            var img = spriteImages[i];
            // Set the texts you want to display to each slide 
            // in a sibling element of your image and edit accordingly
            if ( img.nextElementSibling ) {
                texts.push(img.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
            } else {
                texts.push('');
            }
            spriteImagesSrc.push( img.getAttribute('src' ) );

        }
        console.log(document.querySelector('.canvas-here'), document.querySelector('.canvas-here').innerHeight)
        var initCanvasSlideshow = new CanvasSlideshow({
            sprites: spriteImagesSrc,
            displacementImage: 'img/dmaps/gradient_large.png',
            autoPlay: false,
            stageWidth:document.querySelector('.canvas-here').offsetWidth,
            stageHeight:document.querySelector('.canvas-here').offsetHeight,
            displaceScale: [100, 70],
            fullScreen: false,
            texts: texts,
            textColor: "#224d94",
            interactive: true,
            interactionEvent: "hover",
            centerSprites:  true,
            wacky: true,
            fitCoverSprites: true
        });
```

})();

Comment: can you add a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RensvWalstijn added a link

Comment: @Wakko, a link is not enough. Stack overflow requires you to put the code in the question itself, not just a link to the code somewhere else.